# Issue Getting User Chats - Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get signed in user's chat messages in a B2C Tenant. I am getting 401 Unauthorized error. Tried the same with graph explorer which is also giving same error. I am using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats endpoint. As per MSDN documentation, I have already given permissions to my Azure app. When I am trying this with a non B2C tenant, the API call succeeds.

Please help me with this issue. Error I am seeing is given below.

{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-06-24T15:30:29",
"request-id": "f2804d78-59d2-4917-ae2e-cb73b3eb0872",
"client-request-id": "52452dfc-cae9-d409-92b9-9e9586cab6c3"
}
}
}

Comment: Is the user a consumer account or work account? Does this user have O365 license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some research I found out that B2C tenants don't allow Teams at the first place. I have switched to a B2B tenant and it started working like a charm.